# Webapp mobile admob mmedia

Tags: web-applications, millennial-media

I am trying to use mmedia (millennial media) as ad to my webapp, but I don't know how to do this.

In the sdk that i've received, there are things like "import" and manifest... how could I do this once that my app is webapp... I don't have a manifest or java classes.

Does anyone know a step by step or something like that?

It would be very appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have downloaded the wrong SDK. It sounds like you have downloaded the Android SDK. Go back to MillenialMedia and look for a mobile web SDK.

NB Admob only support Android native apps, not mobile web.